# Java Graphics don't draw

Tags: java

```
public void TestKeyEvent(Graphics g) {
    paintMaze(g);//paint the maze
    g.drawImage(luffyImage, now.getX() * sizex + sizex / 6, now.getY() * sizey + sizey / 6, 
            sizex - sizex / 6, sizey - sizey / 6, null);//this one work

    panel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keycode = e.getKeyCode();
            if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                g.drawImage(luffyImage, now.getX() * sizex + sizex / 6, now.getY() * sizey + sizey / 6+50, sizex - sizex / 6, sizey - sizey / 6, null);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hey!");
            }
        }
    });
```

When I run this project, I can see the luffyImage on screen. When I hit the key, I can see "hey!", but the luffyImage doesn't move. I would appreciate it if you can help me.

Comment: That is because you are redrawing the same image, you need to use proper brackets for the `6+50`

Comment: Have you read [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) ? And have you read [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) ? I think they may help you.

Comment: I am drawing the same image but I draw it in different positions. After seeing your comment, I added brackets but it didn't work;

Comment: Anything drawn in the KeyListener will simply be overwritten by the next UI update cycle. You have to do your drawing from within the paint hierarchy, not from the EventDispatcher thread. As @Abra suggested, have a look at the documentation and the excellent tutorials for this.

Comment: A Graphics object *is not usable* after the painting method to which the Graphics was passed returns.  You cannot keep a Graphics object around to use later.  If you want to visually update something, base your painting on some non-static fields, modify those fields as needed, and call `repaint` to have Swing invoke your painting method again.